# Access url in Twig template

Tags: php, twig, slim

This is my first real PHP/Slim/Twig-project, so please excuse me, if this is a silly question.

In my Twig template, I want to set a css class depending on the url:

```
/personal/... --> <div class="personal">...
/business/... --> <div class="business">...
```

However, I can't access the url from within the template. I found some answers that suggest to use:

```
{{ app.request.uri }}
```

Unfortunately, this results in an empty string. I'm not sure if I have access to my app object at all. This is how I setup my container (Slim Framework 3):

```
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
$view = new Twig('../templates/', ['cache' => false]);
$view->addExtension( new TwigExtension($container['router'], $container['request']->getUri() ) );
return $view;
```

};

And this is how I call the template:

```
public function home ($request, $response, $args) 
{
    $response = $this->view->render($response, "home.twig");
    return $response;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I can, of course, provide more information.

Comment: Slims [TwigExtension](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views/blob/master/TwigExtension.php) seems to provide a method called `currentUrl`, so try `{{ currentUrl() }}`. It also provides some other alternatives.

Comment: That sounds good, thank you! However, how do I "register" the TwigExtension? Right now, I'm receiving an error (Unknown "currentUrl" function). Do I have to add something inside the $container['view'] part?

Comment: You did register it already: `$view->addExtension( new TwigExtension($container['router'], $container['request']->getUri() ) );
`. The functions should be available inside the template. (Assuming TwigExtension in that snippet is `Slim\Views\TwigExtension`)